# Как корректно навести порядок в базе данных PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

База досталась уже в "рабочем" состоянии, где все пользователи и админы наделены правами superuser и мне это совсем не нравится(крах не за горами)... Как правильно перераспределить роли в рабочей системе?
Как я представляю, нужно:

- Убрать всех пользователей из всех групп? (т.к. например удаление у пользователя какой-либо привилегии не сработает, если он состоит в какой-либо другой группе с данной привилегией)
- Создать допустим 2 группы users и admins
- Убрать у всех пользователей все права? (пока пользователь в группе users он наследует привилегии этой группы (и права заданные ему непосредственно при создании)? а там снова superuser)
- распределить пользователей по этим двум группам

Упускаю я что-то важное или вообще всё не так представляю?

Comment: Пользователи - это люди или приложения?

Comment: Вообще очень часто оказывается, что пользователям нужны права на запись во все таблицы и от этого никак не уйти. Хотя это конечно не superuser, удалять то таблицы им нельзя. но никто не мешает такому пользователю удалить все данные из таблицы и если приложение так изначально спроектировано, то это уже не лечится

Comment: @cheops, люди..

Comment: @Mike, на запись нужны и в данном случае, но не нужны например на создание db-функций, триггеров и прочего, и точно не нужны на удаление других пользователей и на доступ к информации, доступной администраторам приложения. От дурака вся информация дампится в несколько мест, всегда можно восстановить, но желательно заниматься этим как можно реже)

Answer (score -1):

Сначала разобраться с правами кому и что нужно, далее создать новые роли, добавить их пользователю, а из остальных убрать. И так с каждым